# Cordova script is not executed

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I got some script that seem to not be executed but I don't know why, I'm trying to debug this with the IOS simulator and safari to see the log.

Here is the content of the index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="appContainer" class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      alert('Wait!'); // is not working
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

and here is the content of the index.js

```
alert("wait"); // That one is working, why ?

var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    console.log("app init");  // not working
    this.bindEvents();
    console.log("app init end");  // not working
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// "load", "deviceready", "offline", and "online".
bindEvents: function() {
    console.log("bind start");  // not working
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener("click", this.onClick, false);
    console.log("bind end");  // not working
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of "this" is the event. In order to call the "receivedEvent"
// function, we must explicitly call "app.receivedEvent(...);"
onDeviceReady: function() {
    console.log("device start");
    app.receivedEvent("deviceready");
    document.getElementById("appContainer").addEventListener("click", this.onClick, false);
    document.getElementById("appContainer").addEventListener("touchstart", this.onClick, false);
    document.getElementById("appContainer").addEventListener("touchend", this.onClick, false);
    console.log("device end");
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector(".listening");
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector(".received");

    listeningElement.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
    receivedElement.setAttribute("style", "display:block;");

    console.log("Received Event: " + id);
},
onClick: function(e) {
    console.log("click"); // not working or it may be the eventlistener
},

};

console.log("init s"); // not working
app.initialize();
console.log("init e"); // not working
```

What I dont understand is 
1 - Why the alert("Wait") in index.html is not working. 
2 - Why the console.log doesn't work execpt the device start, device end and Received Event: deviceready
3 - Why the app.initialize don't seem to be executed (because there are no log) but is actually executed because the device ready event is fired
4 - Why can't I see the log in the onClick function when I trigger a click in the simulator (if the device ready event work,  click, touchstart and touchend should work no ?)

Can somebody explain to me why nothing seems to work properly ?

I'm using cordova 5.3.1 with almost no modification from the init package. I tried to remove ios and add it again but it doesn't change anything.

Thank for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "console" global is an Apache Cordova plugin. It will only be available **ondeviceready**. Have a look here http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.console

Try this

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("app init");
        this.bindEvents();
        console.log("app init end");
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    bindEvents: function() {
        console.log("bind start");
        document.addEventListener("click", this.onClick, false);
        console.log("bind end"); 
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        console.log("device start");
        app.initialize();
        app.receivedEvent("deviceready");
        document.getElementById("appContainer").addEventListener("click", this.onClick, false);
        document.getElementById("appContainer").addEventListener("touchstart", this.onClick, false);
        document.getElementById("appContainer").addEventListener("touchend", this.onClick, false);
        console.log("device end");
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector(".listening");
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector(".received");

        listeningElement.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
        receivedElement.setAttribute("style", "display:block;");

        console.log("Received Event: " + id);
    },
    onClick: function(e) {
        console.log("click"); // not working or it may be the eventlistener
    },

};

//initialize app on device ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", app.onDeviceReady, false);
```

**As for your "alert" mystery**, window.alert compatibility has been proven unreliable in the context of Cordova. I advise you to use

`navigator.notification.alert`

Which is part of plugin-dialogs https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-dialogs

On a side note, there are better ways to manipulate DOM and CSS if that's your goal.

Comment: the alert I place in the html is basically to have the time to open the console in safari, that's why I needed it (only for debug purpose). But the deviceready event is still place in the bindEvent by cordova, I wonder if the way they setup the base template is wrong...

Comment: Do you understand the "console" is a cordova plugin?

Comment: Your right about that, I didn't read it right the first time. Thank :) (but your code is giving me a undefined is not a function evaluating this.initialize)

Comment: I updated it. I didn't test it so you might want to tweak it but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thank a lot for the help :) the only thing that doesn't work now is the click event, it has if the click touchstart and touchend are not triggered. I will investigate that.

Comment: It was the this again that needed to be changed for app :)